# In spring boot, is there a way to set the setting 'spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings' to 'false' programmatically?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In spring boot 2 the setting 'spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings' is defaulted to 'true.' I would like to set it to false; however, I do not want it to have to be configured, i.e. set in the properties file. I want to be able to do it programmatically so that anyone who would use this code does not need to configure it to false as the code requires it to be set to false.

I have searched extensively, but I haven't found a way to do this, nor have I seen anyone talk about it.

Comment: use an environment post processor to add new properties at set it at a highest prescence.

Comment: It worked, thanks!